# Missing step in computing the derivative of a logged pdf

Tags: calculus, probability, machine-learning

I'm having trouble following how the authors got from equation 1 to equation 2.

We have a score $\nabla \log p(y)$, measurement density, $p(y|x)$ (which is gaussian), and a posterior density $p(x|y)$. Using the chain rule, the probability density can be written:

\begin{equation}
p(y) = \int p(x) p(y|x) dx
\end{equation}

Taking the logarithm and differentiating with respect to $y$, and using the fact that for any function $h$, $\nabla h(y) = h(y) \nabla \log h(y)$, we find:

\begin{equation}
\left. \nabla \log p(y) = \int p(x) p(y|x) \nabla_y \log p(y|x) dx \middle/ p(y) \right.
\end{equation}

If I apply the $\nabla \log h(y)$ to $p(y)$, then I no longer have the term $p(x) p(y|x)$... Can anyone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: Which authors? Which equations?

Comment: @joriki, This paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2310.02557.pdf , appendix C (page 16)